# Access denied on client.DownloadFile()

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm creating a script in C# to download files from a FTP, and I'm using the method client.DownloadFile(), and, when I execute the program I get an error:

> Access to "D:/DESTINO" is denied.

```
// Creates WebClient instance
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userxxx", "passwordxxx");
// Download files and saves at
client.DownloadFile("ftp://ftpurl/file.xlsx", @"D:\DESTINO");
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is `D:\DESTINO` a folder? If so, `DownloadFile()` takes a _filename_ as the second argument, not a folder (see the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.8)).

Comment: Yeah, D:\DESTINO is a folder, so, i guess this awnsers the question, the parameter is incorrect. What method do i use to download the file to a folder?

Comment: Try passing a filename to the second argument instead of a folder perhaps? - `D:\DESTINO\file.xlsx`

Comment: I don't think you need to change the method, just what you're passing it. 
 `@"D:\DESTINO\SomeFileName.txt"`

Comment: Well, that solves it, the script worked! Thank you guys!